# How to run a Batch-file automaticly at user-login via administrator

Tags: batch-file, authentication, admin, uac, gpo

Concerns Win10:
We currently facing a problem when we want to run a batch file via gpo. It is a batch file which is supposed to copy files from a directory on a network server to a user directory (about 150 users). It is mandatory that we run this as a user login (NETLOGON) and not at PC startup.
Now the access is of course denied, because the batch file is not started as administrator.
As a workaround we have the idea to move the batch file via GPO into the users' scheduled task planning. There it could be executed as administrator. The problem is that the login information of the administrator is not hashed. Theoretically the users would then have access to the administrator password.

Does anyone know of a way to hash the Password in the file or maybe another way for the users to execute the script automaticly at Login?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not about a specific issue, it's a general research type question _(for which answers may involve some programming)_, and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the program, go to properties, then compatibility and check "Run as Administrator"

Create the VBScript using a text editor (I use Notepad++)

Script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run "cmd /K C:\Program Files (x86)\File\Program.exe", 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Note: that C:\Program Files (x86)\File\Program.exe is the full path to the program with extension. Also, make sure to save it as a .vbs

Now place the VBScript in the startup folder:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Or, alternatively access it by Win+R ⇒ shell:startup ⇒ Enter

I used this instead of a batch file because I did not want that ugly command window showing up.